# Union-closed family generated by n 2-sets

Tags: combinatorics

Let us define a $2$-set as a set with exactly $2$ elements. For a naturel number $n$, let $l(n)$ denote the least possible number of members of a union-closed family of sets generated by $n$ distinct $2$-sets. I'm interested in a useful formula, or in useful formulas, for $l(n)$.

There are easy results, for example $l({r\choose 2}) \leq 2^{r} - 1 - r$, but I would avoid the task of handling this question if there is literature about it. Do you know ? Thanks in advance.

Edit : this question was answered here :
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238142/union-closed-family-generated-by-n-2-sets